# Chrome Alert Box Submits Page Even if Returning False

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

In my application I have a textbox to search for items. In this textbox I want the user to have to enter at least 2 characters before searching. If there's less than 2 characters then I want to display a simple alert box telling the user to enter at least 2 characters. On my text box code looks like:

```js
function checkSearchLen(obj, defaultEnterButton) {
  if (obj.value == 'Search') obj.value = '';

  if (obj.value.length < 2 && event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.returnValue = false;
    event.cancel = true;
    alert('Please ENter at Least 2 Characters');
    //return false;
    obj.select();
    obj.focus();
    return false;
  } else
    doEnterKey(defaultEnterButton);

}

function doEnterKey(s) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.returnValue = false;
    event.cancel = true;
    document.getElementById(s).click();
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="searchtext" id="txtSearch" value="Search" onfocus="this.value = '';this.style.color='black';this.style.fontStyle='normal';" onkeydown="checkSearchLen(this,'MenuBar_imgSearchGo');" name="txtSearch" />
```

In my javascript the function on every keystroke from the user, it checks the keyCode being pressed looking for the 'Enter' input. If the user presses 'Enter' and the number of characters in the textbox is less than 2 then it should alert the user and return false. But regardless the form is still submitted when the user presses 'Enter'.I also noticed it doesn't hit the 'doEnterKey' function it just submits the form. Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

In Internet Explorer everything works as should, the javascript code stops wait for input from the user then continues, returning false. However in chrome the alert box is displayed it and it still submits the form, almost as if it's not returning the false back to the element.

Comment: You are not passing event to `doEnterKey`. And you are not returning false in `doEnterKey`. You should explicitly write `return false;` for that.

Comment: Thanks I will try now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the event object in the call and on ENTER prevent event default.

I used the keypress event and tested on IE, FF and Chrome.

Now the alert message on form submit will not happen because the ENTER is prevented.

```js
function checkSearchLen(event, obj, defaultEnterButton) {
  event = event || window.event;
  if (obj.value == 'Search') obj.value = '';

  if (obj.value.length < 2 && event.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('Please ENter at Least 2 Characters');
    obj.select();
    obj.focus();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else
    doEnterKey(defaultEnterButton);

}

function doEnterKey(s) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.returnValue = false;
    event.cancel = true;
    document.getElementById(s).click();
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.google.com" onsubmit="alert('submit');">
    <input class="searchtext" id="txtSearch" value="Search" onfocus="this.value = '';this.style.color='black';this.style.fontStyle='normal';" onkeypress="checkSearchLen(event, this,'MenuBar_imgSearchGo');" name="txtSearch" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @gaemaf I guess onkeypress was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The best method to deal with this kind of problems is by using Jquery...just a few lines of Jquery code is capable of doing what you did in the entire program!

Comment: Wuuldn't that be same thing just different syntax? Or did you mean like a jquery dialog?

Comment: I think Jquery code is less prone to errors...and i didnt mean anything like a jquery dialog ...the event handlers in Jquery does things better!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternate answer is to do checking in form submit event and cancel that submit event based on invalid input. This will prevent page post back. Actually, this is the same approach that ASP.Net framework takes when a page has ASP.Net validators in it with client-side validation turned on.

Also, there is no need to cancel the event in `doEnterKey`, so I have commented two lines in that function.

The following code will work as I have tested on my side. There are two aspects to the logic being used:

1. A global variable `stopSubmit` decides if form submit event will be canceled or not. If this variable is true then form submit event will cancel.
2. The original form submit event code of the form is being pre-pended with our custom JavaScript that will return a false in case the form submit needs to be canceled. This is happening when body loads for the page i.e. body's onload event calls `setFormSubmit` to modify existing form submit code. If everything was valid, then original form submit code executes without issues and page posts back.

   ```
   <body onload="setFormSubmit()">
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
       <div>
           First name:
           <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey" /><br />
           Last name:
           <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse" /><br />
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
           <input type="text" onkeydown="checkSearchLen(this,'MenuBar_imgSearchGo');" />
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="MenuBar_imgSearchGo"/>
       </div>
       <script>
           var stopSubmit = false;
           function setFormSubmit() {

               document.forms[0].setAttribute("onsubmit", " var stopPostback = StopPostback(); if(stopPostback === true) { return false; } " + (document.forms[0].onsubmit === null ? "" : document.forms[0].onsubmit));
           }
           function checkSearchLen(obj, defaultEnterButton) {
               if (obj.value === 'Search') obj.value = '';

               if (obj.value.length < 2 && event.keyCode == 13) {
                   event.returnValue = false;
                   event.cancel = true;
                   stopSubmit = true;
                   alert('Please ENter at Least 2 Characters');
                   obj.select();
                   obj.focus();
                   return false;
               } else {
                   stopSubmit = false;
                   doEnterKey(defaultEnterButton);
               }
           }

           function doEnterKey(s) {
               if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                   //event.returnValue = false;
                   //event.cancel = true;
                   document.getElementById(s).click();
               }
           }
           function StopPostback() {
               if (stopSubmit === true) {
                   stopSubmit = false;
                   return true;
               }
               return false;
           }
       </script>
   </form>
   ```